# Fetching rows from office excel with table CoercionType in Task Pane Add in using Office Js

Tags: office365, office-js

We are developing excel Add In using office Js version 1.1 and user will be uploading data to the server from the excel.

Currently we are using Table coercion type to fetch the rows from table. One of limitation we are getting that user has to convert the columns and rows as table manually before getting selected rows.

If user doesn't convert it as table manually using given in excel. Its throwing error like below. **The current selector is not compatible with the specified coercion type**

Is there any workaround for this? Basically we don't want user to forcefully convert the data into table before uploading data.

Any suggestion and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! instead of using the Table coercionType use the Matrix coercionType. that must solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give a try with Matrix coercionType, If Its fits to our requirement.

Comment: It works but I'll have  to change the way I am managing the fetching rows from sheet.